# Organization chart in ASP.Net

Tags: c#

I am trying to explore other options in ASP.net to create organizational chart without using any third party tool. I am using C# for my ASP.net pages. I want some ideas/code to implement a simple organizational chart.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Tree Chart Generator](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/TreeGenerator.aspx) on CodeProject.

Answer (score 1):

Sample table structure is here:
http://unifosys.com/hierarchy-chart/Create_Organization_Chart_from_Database_Sample.html